# Shell script for making database backups works only from prompt

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I have a shell script that works fine from the command prompt, but from my cron job it throws `unexpected operator`

```
BACKUP=/var/www/backups/mysql
NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")
MUSER="root"
MPASS="secr3T"
MHOST="localhost"
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

find $BACKUP/* -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;

DBS="$($MYSQL -h $MHOST -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do

if [ "$db" == "myDBase" ]; then
    if [ "$db" != "performance_schema" ]; then
        FILE=$BACKUP/mysql_backup_$db.$NOW.tar.gz
        $MYSQLDUMP -h $MHOST -u $MUSER -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
        echo $db
        fi
    fi
done
```

I am accessing the script using crontab `20 0 * * * var/www/backups/backup.site.sh`

The errors I get are:

```
/var/www/backups/backup.mysql.sh: 20: [: information_schema: unexpected operator
/var/www/backups/backup.mysql.sh: 20: [: mysql: unexpected operator
/var/www/backups/backup.mysql.sh: 20: [: olb: unexpected operator
/var/www/backups/backup.mysql.sh: 20: [: performance_schema: unexpected operator
```

I am running the latest version of mySQL on Ubuntu 14.04. Doe anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Just `unexpected error`?

Comment: What is the crontab exact line? My guess is that you should be using absolute path and you use relative path and/or assume that .bashrc is initialized within the cron job (it is not).

Comment: Does your script start with a `#!` line? I vaguely remember Ubuntu using /bin/dash for cron jobs by default rather than /bin/bash.

Comment: Also what is the purpose of `if [ "$db" == "myDBase" ]; then if [ "$db" != "performance_schema" ]`? You're trying to match `$db` two times.

Comment: I have adapted my question with the items requested by you guys. And there is a commented out line in there which I removed. No first linen stating `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: *Always* begin scripts with the proper `#!` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without specifying your shell, you will get /bin/sh by default (tested on Ubuntu 14.04). The `[` built-in for sh does not support the `==` operator, so sh doesn't know how to compare `$db` and `myDBase` on line 20.

You should always start your scripts with a "#!" line to specify a shell. To get bash, the first line would be `#!/bin/bash`.